# WebAssembly pre-fetch external resources and then use fopen on it

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, webassembly

I have a C++ project that uses EMSDK to compile to WebAssembly. I have an asset that my project loads, a bundle.zip that I currently use the '--embed-file' flag from the SDK at compile time, and this works.

However, I would like to know if there is a way, in HTML or JavaScript, to pre-load this asset. So, instead of having to rebuild my project every time I change something in 'bundle.zip', I would just upload it and keep the same '.wasm'.

Is this option available? When searching online, I only found questions and answers related to C#'s Blazor, which is not related to what I want.

A **crucial** detail is that my application needs to read this file from the file system, as if it were on the native platform, not on the web (it does a fopen).

Comment: Doesn’t `--preload-file` do exactly that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using JavaScript to fetch the '`bundle.zip`' file at runtime, and then use the [Emscripten Filesystem API](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html) to make it accessible to your WebAssembly module.
That way, you can change '`bundle.zip`' without recompiling your WebAssembly module.

```
+-------------+     +-----------------+     +-------------+
| C++ Project | --> | Compile to WASM | --> | Web Browser |
+-------------+     +-----------------+     +-------------+
      |                   |                        |
      |                   |                        |
      |                   |                        +-- Fetch bundle.zip
      |                   |                        |   at runtime
      |                   |                        |
      |                   |                        +-- Write to Virtual FS
      |                   |                        |   (Emscripten FS API)
      |                   |                        |
      |                   |                        +-- Access via fopen()
```

First, remove the `--embed-file` flag from your Emscripten build command. That will stop embedding 'bundle.zip' into your WebAssembly module.

Check if, as commented, the `--preload-file` option mentioned in [Emscripten » Porting » Files and File Systems » Packaging Files](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/packaging_files.html) would work

When compiling your project with Emscripten, use the `--preload-file` flag followed by the path to '`bundle.zip`'. Emscripten then generates a '`.data`' file alongside your '`.wasm`' and '`.js`' files.

```bash
emcc your_project.cpp -o your_project.html --preload-file path/to/bundle.zip
```

The generated JavaScript loader code will automatically fetch the '`.data`' file when loading your WebAssembly module. That means '`bundle.zip`' is downloaded separately from your '`.wasm`' file, but in a way that is transparent to your application.

The contents of '`bundle.zip`' are automatically unpacked into the Emscripten virtual filesystem at runtime. Your application should then use `fopen` to access the files as if they were on a regular filesystem.

To update '`bundle.zip`', you simply replace the '`.data`' file on your server. There is no need to recompile your WebAssembly module unless the C++ code itself changes.

---

Or use JavaScript to fetch '`bundle.zip`' when your web page loads. You can use the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for that.

Before you call any functions from your WebAssembly module that need '`bundle.zip`', make sure to mount a virtual filesystem and write your fetched file into it: that will make '`bundle.zip`' accessible as if it were part of a normal filesystem.

Your C++ code should now be able to use `fopen` to open '`bundle.zip`', as it would on a native filesystem.

```js
// Fetch the bundle.zip
fetch('path/to/bundle.zip')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(data => {
    // Convert the fetched data into a Uint8Array
    var uint8View = new Uint8Array(data);

    // Initialize the Emscripten file system
    FS.writeFile('/bundle.zip', uint8View);

    // Now you can call your WebAssembly functions that use fopen
    // For example: Module.ccall('yourFunction', 'returnType', ['arg1Type'], [arg1Value]);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('Error fetching bundle.zip:', err));
```

`FS.writeFile` (part of the Emscripten Filesystem API) is used to write the fetched file to the Emscripten virtual filesystem.

---

The [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77468927/6309) proposes  a good implementation of the solution discussed above.

The use of `<link rel="preload" href="/bundle.zip" as="fetch" ...>` in the `<head>` section hints to the browser that '`bundle.zip`' is a resource that will be needed soon, which can improve loading performance as the browser can start fetching it early in the page load process.
A `<canvas>` element is set up in the HTML body, which is likely used for rendering content from the WebAssembly module.

The CSS ensures a consistent box model and resets default margins, alongside styles for the canvas and container elements.

The `Module` object is correctly configured with the `canvas` element and `noInitialRun` set to `true`, indicating that the WebAssembly module should not run immediately on load. The `onRuntimeInitialized` callback is used to fetch '`bundle.zip`' once the WebAssembly environment is initialized.

The `fetch` API is used to load '`bundle.zip`' into an ArrayBuffer. That buffer is then converted into a Uint8Array and written to the Emscripten virtual filesystem at the path '`/bundle.zip`' using `FS.writeFile`. Once '`bundle.zip`' is written to the filesystem, `Module.callMain()` is called to start the main application.

Finally, the script `carimbo.js` is included, which is presumably the JavaScript generated by Emscripten and responsible for loading and running the WebAssembly module.

Answer (score 1):

After the response of @VonC, this is my final HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="preload" href="/bundle.zip" as="fetch" type="application/octet-stream" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
    }

    body {
      line-height: 1.5;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    canvas {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"></canvas>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

      var Module = {
        canvas,
        noInitialRun: true,
        onRuntimeInitialized: () => {
          fetch("/bundle.zip")
            .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
            .then((data) => {
              const uint8View = new Uint8Array(data);
              FS.writeFile("/bundle.zip", uint8View);
              Module.callMain();
            });
        },
      };
    </script>
    <script src="carimbo.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well done, upvoted. I have included in my answer some comments on your implementation.